# All frontend languages/solutions

Tags: javascript, plugins, browser, frontend

Are these all the languages/solutions you could use in frontend?

- javascript+html+css
- flash
- java
- silverlight (c#, ruby, python etc)

And what is a plugin for Safari and Firefox written in? Is it low-level languages like C++?

Comment: ...front-end langauges for web applications only?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: Yeah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FireFox plugins use XUL, [https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XUL](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XU), HTML, JavaScript and CSS;they are called chrome applications. In fact the browser itself is a chrome application. It also uses XPCOM for some things, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM. From that link "XPCOM components be used and implemented in JavaScript, Java, and Python in addition to C++".

And if your curious, Microsoft's XAML was pretty much taken from XUL.

As far as I know for plugins in Safari/Chrome and other non-IE, they just use HTML, JavaScript CSS. For IE plugins, check this out, http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?design.4.423268.5

Answer (score 1):

firefox: [How to create extensions for firefox](http://blog.mozilla.com/addons/2009/01/28/how-to-develop-a-firefox-extension/)

plugins for chrome, you can write those in simple Html, javascript

Answer (score 1):

Simply put (and as you probably well aware), and to use the long-standing terminology, there are two sides to a (say, web) experience, the client and the server:

1. Any language that can run without a
   call to the web server in the client
   (i.e. the web browser) is
   **client-side** (Javascript is the
   obvious example);
2. a language that runs on the server,
   but produces content that the client
   can request, is **server-side** (Ruby,
   Python, Perl, etc.)

Plugins like Flash or Silverlight are a separate case. Although themselves written in languages functioning at a lower-level than client-side scripts, they nevertheless operate in a *client browser* with the plugin, and - once loaded - Actionscript (say) will run in the browser, client-side.

To complicate matters, HTML and Javascript can be used to write (e.g.) OS X widgets and Browser plugins and - although they may call on server functions for (say) data - they're still *client-side*.

Further, the ability of [HTML5 to store data](http://www.weboshelp.net/webos-tutorials/156-palm-webos-html5-database-storage-tutorial), and the rise of [NoSQL](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2010/05/11/nosql-architecture/) solutions, mean that the division is no longer as clear-cut as it once was.

Answer (score 0):

Front end is never limited to what languages/platforms, frameworks, APIs etc. that you could use.  However, you could say that HTML, JavaScript (and its frameworks), CSS are the main platforms you are going to use while front-end developing. But you should keep in mind that complex issues require specific knowledge therefore, it's good to know other languages/platforms as well. 
Regarding your second question, even though most of them use HTML, CSS and Javacript.

To learn more about what language and platforms mozilla uses check out this link and click on specific documentation: 
https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2014/06/05/how-to-develop-firefox-extension/

Checkout this tutorial on how to make a chrome extension:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

Check out this tutorial on how to make a Safari extension:
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-safari-extension-from-scratch--net-15050